# Huffman Tree ideas. Traversing the tree and returning the path in C

Tags: c, recursion, huffman-code

So I'm building a huffman coder in C for my data structures class project. I've gotten to the point where I have my tree and the structure of the tree seems fine. Now I need a way to traverse the tree to find letters and return the path so it can be printed to a file. The tree is fixed and only the last nodes hold a character value

For example let's say you're looking for the letter 'a' and you go throw the the tree
right->left->left->right
What kind of recursion or loop could I use that would return the path. right = 1, left = 0 so returning something like 1001 then I can print that to the file.

Ideally a string would be best, but if you have any better ideas please let me know!

Comment: If this is a fixed tree you're going to repeatedly rescan then it might be easier to build - or at least cache - the reverse mapping so you can just look up 'a' and find the string '1001'. (Although obviously you should emit those as a sequence of four bits not four characters.)

Comment: You should better post the representation of your tree. Are you using dynamically allocated nodes, with pointers? If yes, which pointers do the nodes contain? Are you using an array to hold your tree? If yes, how did you implement pointers? The best answer to your question may depend on these details.

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't. Searching a tree for every symbol to encode is a terrible waste of time.

Instead you would scan the entire tree *once*, recursively, and generate a lookup table of all of the symbols and their associated codes. Then use the table for encoding, which can be indexed or mapped by the symbol.

Comment: Alright I'll try that. Do you have any ideas on how I code get the codes. The best thing I can think of so far is passing in an array of char's and a length to an auxiliary function, then setting the elements of the array to 1 or 0 depending on if the tree goes left or right. The only thing is that would limit my string length.

Comment: You traverse the entire tree recursively, building up and tearing down the code based on the branches taken (0 or 1). When you get to a leaf, you write out the symbol in that leaf and the code you have built up to the table.